# NGINX: Prevent users from viewing website on port (example.com:5000)

Tags: ubuntu, nginx, django

I've setup an ubuntu VPS, which is running a django app. I'm using `waitress` as a WSGI server and `whitenoise` to serve static files. Also `nginx` serves the media folder. The current setup works great at `example.com` but I would like to prevent the website from showing up to `example.com:5000` since the media files are being serve at this port.

The command i am using to run the server is:

```
web: PYTHONUNBUFFERED=true env/bin/waitress-serve --port=$PORT project.wsgi:application
```

And the nginx configuration:

```
upstream app_server {
    server 127.0.0.1:5000 fail_timeout=0;
}

server {
    listen 80 default_server;
    server_name _;

    client_max_body_size 4G;
    keepalive_timeout 10;

    location /uploads/ {
        alias /opt/media/;
    }

    location / {
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
        proxy_set_header Host $http_host;
        proxy_redirect off;
        proxy_pass http://app_server;
    }
}
```

Is it possible to hide the website from `example.com:5000`?

Ps. Worst case - can I also serve the media at port 5000?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From your config it looks like nginx is't listening to port 5000. Thus, you should investigate what is actually listening on this port, and block it for outer world - most easy way would be binding it to localhost only. This way it will be accessible to nginx, but not to anyone who's not on this exact machine.

Comment: That is exactly what I am looking for! Can you indicate how I can block it for the outer world and bind it to localhost only?

Comment: From the documentation: "--host=ADDR
    Hostname or IP address on which to listen, default is ‘0.0.0.0’, which means “all IP addresses on this host”". Thus you have to configure 127.0.0.1 as bind IP.

Comment: And learn to use documentation. Or change speciality.

Comment: I'm not a sys admin - was just messing around with a VPS out of curiosity.. Adding `--host=ADDR` fixed the issue! Thank you very much for your help!